# Div image background is hidden by child table on print

Tags: html, css

I made an invoice which is composed of a table inside a div.

The div has a background image.
On regular screen view, the background for the invoice is working well.
See screen view:
[See screen view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmKk8.png)

However on print preview, the div background is hidden by the table.
[See print view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYfdW.png)

How can I make the print preview like what I see on the screen? I don't want the table to hide the div background image.

HTML:

```
<div class="invoices">
<div ng-repeat="table in invoicesTables">
    <div class="header row"><br>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="col-xs-12">
            <img src="src/print_statement.PNG" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <h5>Customer: <strong style="font-size: 12pt">{{client.Name}}</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <h5 class="invoiceNumber">Invoice No.: <strong style="font-size: 13pt; color:red">{{table.invoiceNumber}}</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <h5>
                <span>Date: </span><strong style="font-size: 12pt;">{{today | date: fullDate}}</strong>
                <!-- <span style="float:left">From: </span><strong style="font-size: 12pt; float:right;">{{table.startDate | date: fullDate}}</strong>
                </br></br>
                <span style="float:left">Till: </span><strong style="font-size: 12pt; float:right;">{{table.endDate | date: fullDate}}</strong> -->
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="invoicebg">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Delivery No.</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Description</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="i in table.tableInvoices | orderBy : '-Date' | reverse ">
                    <td>{{i.Date | date: fullDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.Id}}</td>
                    <td colspan="2">{{i.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.Amount | number : 2}}$</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <div ng-style="emptySpaces[$index]"></div>


        <div style="font-weight:bold" class="tfoot row">
            <div class="col-xs-3" style="border-top:2px solid black;">
                أو ما بعادله بالليرة اللبنانية
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7" style="border-top:2px solid black; background-color:lightgray;">
                {{table.totalInLetters}} Dollars <span style="float:right;">فقط</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:2px solid black;">
                {{table.total | number: 2}}$
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.invoicebg{
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    background: url('../src/invoicewatermark.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center ;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code you are having the issue with, please...

Comment: Please show us the html and css code, i imagine could be the property **background**, trye this, put in your css **background:none !important** to your table, if does work also try put that property to tr an td too and telll us how did it go

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav, thanks. Indeed, I had to put css background:none!important for the tds of the table.

Comment: Great, I will place my answer so that the votes in favor plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, put in your css **background:none !important** to your table, if doesn't work also try put that property to **tr** and **td** too and tell us how did it go

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in CSS file:

```
.table {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```